# Переход к блоку при листинге

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть обычная разметка сайта, с обычными блоками.
Ниже есть блок с атрибутом: `height: 100%`

```css
.block-1 { background: green; }
.block-2 { background: yellow; }
.block-3 { background: blue; }

.block-1, .block-2, .block-3, .footer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">Блок 1</div>
<div class="block-2">Блок 2</div>
<div class="block-3">Блок 3</div>

<div class="footer">
  Блок с высотой 100%
</div>
```

Вопрос: Каким образом сделать чтобы когда пользователь пролистал все содержимое блоков 1 - 2 - 3, как только дошел до низа последнего блока (block-3). и если он еще начал листать ниже, его плавно перекидывает на блок **footer** с высотой 100%.

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что как только блок footer появился снизу на экране он тут же должен занять 100% экрана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что правильно понял...
Скажу сразу, что тут пример не работает, не знаю почему, можно его скопировать запустить на компе будет работать. можно  еще добавить плавности подъема 
P.S. Кстати в codepen тоже не работает...

```js
/* захватываем элемент footer*/
var footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
window.onscroll = function() {

  /**/
  /*динамический во время скрола получаем его координаты*/
  var footerCor = footer.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  /*динамический во время скрола получаем height body*/
  var doc = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  var cor = footerCor - doc;

  /* и тут условие, когда footer появляется в зоне видимости экрана */
  if (cor <= 0 && cor >= -100) {
    /*срабатыевает событие scrollIntoView(top) для footer*/
    footer.scrollIntoView(top);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

.block-1 {
  background: green;
}

.block-2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.block-3 {
  background: blue;
}

.block-1,
.block-2,
.block-3,
.footer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block-3 {
  height: 120%;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">Блок 1
</div>
<div class="block-2">Блок 2
</div>
<div class="block-3">
</div>

<div class="footer">
  Блок с высотой 100%
</div>
```

Comment: все бы отлично. но, если листать обратно вверх - не пускает, снова бросает на .footer

Comment: @Денис, я в курсе, по этому и такое условие... Я тебе подал идею, я просто не знаю всех требуемых моментов, а гадать не хочется...   Ты, думаю понял в чем именно состоит суть, тут уж дальше думаю разберешься...  Просто надо условие написать под свои требования...